# How can I add UIView in **spriteKit**?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, sprite-kit

I am developing a game project using **SpriteKit** framework, now my requirement is i want to add UIView

control in my spriteKit project but unable to do it.

```
UIView *myview=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 480)];
[myview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.scene.view addSubview:myview];
```

Currently i am adding UIView to SKScene like this but it is not working . 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 [UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:myview duration:0.25 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve completion:^(BOOL finished) {
// What to do when its finished.
[self.scene.view addSubview:myview];

}];
```